# Asp.net gridview is loading data in Firefox but not in IE7

Tags: asp.net, gridview, browser

Hope things are well with you...
I am facing a problem with Asp.net gridview....

Actually my gridview has to load data based on date range.
I mean I need to give start date and end date to pull the data to the grid.

When i give date range like 7 days..Grid is loading in IE7.
But when i give date range like 1 or 2 months...it is saying "Page cannot be displayed"...

But Mozilla is working fine with this case. 
And my IE is Javascript enabled also.

Please provide me the solution..what could be the rootcause of this issue...

I will be thankful to you, if I get solution for this..

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Naveen

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is an indication that somewhere an html tag is not being closed properly.  I've seen this when looking at tables built by repeater controls that were missing an `</tr>` tag or something along those lines.  it may be another tag, but the basic issue that this looks like to me can be rephrased up as this:

> I have a page being built based on a DataBound control that grows in
>   proportion to the number of rows.  This can be a DataGrid, or a
>   Repeater, whatever.  In IE it will start to crash when very large
>   amounts of data get loaded, but it is fine with smaller data sets and
>   fine in Firefox (and sometimes Chrome or Safari)

The basic reason this is happening is that in general, browsers are forgiving of improperly constructed html.  However, even though most browsers are forgiving, different browsers parse the html and translate it into what's seen on your screen differently.

In my experience, I've seen this issue only three times, and all three times, it turned out to be an unclosed html tag, and in all cases, it was IE that bombed with large data sets. Based on that experience, I believe that after a while, IE just gives up - it's no longer able to compensate for the poorly formed html being output by the page.  Firefox seems to be able to handle it a little better.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you very much for your important note here...i will follow as you said...